# 22.04 suddenly will not write to any USB media

Tags: usb, permissions, 22.04

I recently installed Ubuntu 22.04 and completely removed Windows so this is NOT a dual system. Everything was working fine but suddenly I can not write to any USB media even though they all say that permission to read/write IS enabled. The drives do mount and they can be read but not written. I was using all of these USB drives with no problems until two days ago. The laptop also has a SD card slot which is working fine both reading and writing, also if I use an SD card in an external USB adapter it works fine. I have also tried loging in as the root but no change. I have also tried formatting a USB stick from Ubuntu but the results are still the same.

Please advise! Thank you...

Comment: Maybe I'm answering my own question but I just tried to reformat a USB stick as exFAT on my Mac and now it's working to write from Ubuntu. The thing is though that 3 USB sticks just suddenly stopped letting me write to them but there's more: I tried reformatting several sticks with Ubuntu's disk utility choosing for maximum compatibility with all computers and these USB can not be read by Mac or the same Ubuntu device that  made them. I needed to reformat them using the Mac before they could be mounted again.

Comment: Ok, the problem is not resolved BUT when I formatted one of the USB drives (the larger newer USB 3.0 drive) as exFAT it works but the others when I format them in the same way can be read and not written. I hope somebody can help. Thanks...

Comment: I guess the cards have gone bad.

Comment: No, there's nothing wrong with the USB sticks. They work in all other computers fine and 3 sticks didn't all go bad at the same moment. As I said, one works now formatted exFAT but the other two do not...

Comment: You should edit the question and lay it out more clearly what you tried and not tried, what works and doesn't, break it down.

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, I encountered a similar problem. I found [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/622101/552611) on the Unix & Linux Stack Exchange, and it resolved my problems. "[T]he problem wasn't permissions to read the path to the device itself, but to the /media/[user] directory. Probably some problem caused by multiple dist-upgrades." To confirm that's in fact the issue, run the following in terminal `ls /media/[user]`. For me, confirmation looked like `ls: cannot access '/media/[user]': No such file or directory`. So then, to get back ownership of the directory, I ran `sudo chown [user] /media/[user]`. That worked for me.